# nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Tags: nvidia, 16.04

I am using `nvidia GeForce GT 630 oem rev a1` graphics card on  my embedded hardware. I can run Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS fine on my hardware.
But since I have nvidia graphics card and dual monitors, I wanted to use nvidia TwinView and therefore to achieve that was trying to install nvidia drivers.

I booted up the machine and logged into it and used the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
```

I chose 361 because the ppa link says that it is the latest driver.

After installing the driver, I reboot my machine. I can see bootup messages for like two(2) seconds and then the screen goes black with some cursor blinking on bottom left corner of the screen and then the system turns off/shutsdown/crashes.

Has anyone seen this ?

Thanks,
Manik

my last few syslog messages are:

```
Jul 18 15:59:21 manik dbus[2691]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
Jul 18 15:59:21 manik systemd[1]: Started Thermal Daemon Service.
Jul 18 15:59:21 manik systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
Jul 18 15:59:21 manik systemd[1]: Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
Jul 18 15:59:21 manik systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik dbus[2691]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' unit='polkitd.service'
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik thermald[2656]: 13 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:3c:3 (6:60:3)
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik thermald[2656]: Polling mode is enabled: 4
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started Permit User Sessions.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik avahi-daemon[2645]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started Save/Restore Sound Card State.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik irqbalance[2646]:  * Starting SMP IRQ Balancer: irqbalance
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik apport[2652]:  * Starting automatic crash report generation: apport
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik speech-dispatcher[2661]:  * speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik avahi-daemon[2645]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik avahi-daemon[2645]: Server startup complete. Host name is manik.local. Local service cookie is 3952325250.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik apport[2652]:    ...done.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand".
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik cron[2718]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik irqbalance[2646]:    ...done.
Jul 18 15:59:22 manik cron[2718]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jul 18 15:59:23 manik thermald[2656]: sysfs read failed constraint_0_max_power_uw
Jul 18 15:59:23 manik thermald[2656]: sysfs read failed max_brightness
Jul 18 15:59:23 manik thermald[2656]: sysfs write failed trip_point_0_temp
Jul 18 15:59:23 manik thermald[2656]: sysfs write failed trip_point_0_temp
Jul 18 15:59:23 manik systemd[1]: Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
Jul 18 15:59:23 manik systemd[1]: Started LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
Jul 18 15:59:23 manik systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jul 18 15:59:23 manik systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Jul 18 15:59:23 manik systemd[1]: Starting Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
Jul 18 15:59:23 manik systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik NetworkManager[2716]: <info>  [1468882764.5041] NetworkManager (version 1.2.0) is starting...
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik polkitd[2761]: started daemon version 0.105 using authority implementation `local' version `0.105'
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik dbus[2691]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik systemd[1]: Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks.
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik accounts-daemon[2677]: started daemon version 0.6.40
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik systemd[1]: Started Accounts Service.
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik NetworkManager[2716]: <info>  [1468882764.6430] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik NetworkManager[2716]: <info>  [1468882764.6948] manager[0x9c848e8]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik NetworkManager[2716]: <info>  [1468882764.6949] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik whoopsie[2659]: [15:59:24] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik whoopsie[2659]: [15:59:24] Could not get the Network Manager state:
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik whoopsie[2659]: [15:59:24] GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik NetworkManager[2716]: <info>  [1468882764.9092] dns-mgr[0x9c7d220]: set resolv-conf-mode: dnsmasq, plugin="dnsmasq"
Jul 18 15:59:24 manik NetworkManager[2716]: <info>  [1468882764.9092] dns-mgr[0x9c7d220]: using resolv.conf manager 'resolvconf'
Jul 18 15:59:25 manik systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Jul 18 15:59:25 manik systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Jul 18 15:59:25 manik systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Jul 18 15:59:25 manik systemd-sleep[2759]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (nil)  error: No such file or directory
Jul 18 15:59:25 manik systemd-sleep[2771]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
Jul 18 15:59:25 manik systemd-sleep[2759]: Suspending system...
```

some of nvidia logs from syslog had this too:

```
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik nvidia-persistenced: Started (2344)
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik nvidia-persistenced: Failed to query NVIDIA devices. Please ensure that the NVIDIA device files (/dev/nvidia*) exist, and that user 121 has read and write permissions for those files.
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik nvidia-persistenced: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (2344)
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik systemd-udevd[1353]: Process '/sbin/modprobe nvidia-uvm' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik nvidia-persistenced: Started (2351)
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik systemd[1]: Found device ST9160314AS hd_home.
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/e36694c6-dfd1-4136-b30c-db29a5582450...
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (2351)



Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   21.348555] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   21.351611] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   21.355553] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   21.355635] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 245
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   21.355720] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   21.355726] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  361.45.18  Tue Jun 21 17:29:18 PDT 2016
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   21.952721] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  361.45.18  Tue Jun 21 17:58:16 PDT 2016
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   22.841440] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   22.841444] NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   22.841445] NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   22.841447] NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
Jul 18 15:59:20 manik kernel: [   22.841448] NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: what does that do to cause this problem ?

Comment: Did it work for you? Do you have UEFI?

Comment: I can not change the BIOS. Here in my company we have a readable BIOS.

Comment: What is "readable" BIOS? You need to change the settings or do not use proprietary drivers if you are using UEFI.

Comment: readable meaning - I can not change BIOS settings and save them. It does not allow. 
Again, what does "Secure boot" has to do with this issue ? I am trying to understand.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules

Comment: FYI, with our custom toolchain(based on Suse) we do install nvidia 331 drivers for the same hardware and that works fine.

Comment: It depends on kernel settings.

Comment: we are not using UEFI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the log says at the end `systemd-sleep[2759]: Suspending system...` , I have disabled the acpi support for the kernel. And it works. I can see my desktop screen and everything.

I used the kernel parameter in the grub command line as `acpi=off`